# Images with width/height percentages showing up stretched

Tags: css

I have about 15 images, one after the other, formatted as so:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>
       <a href=""><img src="img.jpg"></a>
    </p>
    <p>
       <a href=""><img src="img.jpg"></a>
    </p>        
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo img {
   height: 75%;
   width: 75%;
}
```

This has shown up in every browser I've used, even some older IE versions, but it wasn't until I was using a friend's Macbook that I viewed the site and the images were extremely stretched out. It is an older OSx version (10.5.8), but both Chrome and Safari have the images stretched out.

I'm trying to get each image to show up 75% smaller than it is. The images vary in size.

Is it possible to fix this without manually resizing each image?

Comment: What about `min-height` and `min-width` css properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

> Use only width:100%; on the image and remove height: 100%;. This will
>   tell the browser to resize the image in a way to respect the 100% of
>   the width, or more like, fix your width then stretch your legs.

Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
.foo img {
   min-height: 100px;
   min-width: 100px;
 }
```